# Scroll Modal Containing Chart Horizontally on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a chartjs chart on a modal and it looks fine on the laptop. I am trying to view the modal on the mobile as well but the modal gets cut off on the right. Even though I have set the modal content to overflow, I can only scroll on the laptop, it doesn't work on the mobile phone.

Does anyone have any advice how we can view the contents of the modal properly or enable it to scroll on a mobile phone? (I am not using bootstrap)

Would appreciate any help!

Code for the modal css was adapted from here: https://css-tricks.com/considerations-styling-modal/

Here is the code:

html code

```
    <div class="modal-overlay" id="modal-overlay"></div>

    <div id="mymodal" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <canvas id="mychart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

css code

```
 .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1010;
        margin-left: 5%;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 600px;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 50px 20px 20px;
    overflow: auto;

}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-overlay {
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

javascript code

```
var modal = document.getElementById('mymodal');
modal.style.display = "flex";
var modal_overlay = document.getElementById('modal-overlay');
modal_overlay.style.display = "flex";


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal_overlay.style.display = "none";

};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal_overlay) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        modal_overlay.style.display = "none";

    }
}
// d is my data that is a dictionary

var labels = [];
var questions = [];
var correct = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    var l = d[i]['a'];
    var q = d[i]['b'];
    var c = d[i]['c'];
    labels.push(l);
    questions.push(q);
    correct.push(c);
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("mychart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "test",
            backgroundColor: "#38AADD",
            data: questions
        },
        {
            label: "test2",
            backgroundColor: "#72B026",
            data: correct
        }

    ]
```

Comment: Can you link to a working example of this?

Answer (score 0):

The **CSS** is not set up properly. I would change the following, to make it better:

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1010;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    height: 400px;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 50px 20px 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

With `%` you have a more consistent size for each screen.

The scrolling problem I would suggest to add and change the following:

```
.modal-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

With the above it will give a vertical scroll to each screen, if this is not desirable you could only apply it to screens smaller than 900px:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .modal-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
```